# Can't Connect to Work Network with Personal Laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wpa

I'm trying to use my personal laptop (Windows 7 Home Premium) on my work's wireless network, but I can't seem to authenticate and get in. I believe the network is using WPA2 (Enterprise?)

It asks for a username and password. For the username, I've tried "Domain\Username", but that doesn't seem to work. Weirdest thing is that on my personal iPod touch, I can use "Domain\Username" and my password for the network, and it connects just fine!

Anyone know a reason why it won't work on my laptop too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably security checks that are run on your system while connecting that fail. Is the work network supposed to allow personal devices to be connected? Most I am familiar with are not.

Some companies offer guest wireless networks that do not allow access to the "main" network resources.

I would go so far as to say, unless there is compelling reason otherwise, a business network should never allow connection of non-business owned assets, due to security and privacy issues, and in accordance with best practices.

Comment: There is a guest network, but I do not want to use that because I need access to certain Intranet resources. I can connect to the work network just fine with my personal iPod touch, so I don't see why my Windows 7 machine cannot.

Comment: Have you talked with your local IT staff? Are they aware you wish to access internal and intranet resources with your personal system?

Comment: Turns out there were hidden security checks in place! Thanks for the tip; talked with the IT staff and they helped me get online.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question; looks like I would need to upgrade my Windows 7 laptop to Windows 7 Professional if I want to connect to a domain.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/can-windows-7-home-premium-join-domains-even/32db6241-4b0e-4fab-a10f-9e282efc6d87

Comment: But you are not joining your computer to the domain, you are simple connecting to the work network. Is your iPod actually joining the domain? I'd imagine probably not. Unless the wireless network requires joining to the domain for access, this may not be your solution.